# Julia Gadfly 'Geom not defined' error

Tags: julia, gadfly

Having used Gadfly without issue since learning Julia, today I receice the error

```
Gadfly.plot(x=1:10,y=rand(10),Geom.line)
ERROR: Geom not defined
```

I have updated packages with no change in functionality. See the attached screenshot:

[image: Gadfly Error]

Comment: What does `versioninfo()` give?  I just tried `using Gadfly` & `plot(x=1:10,y=rand(10),Geom.line)` and it worked fine.  I'm using `Julia Version 0.3.2-pre+33` and the same version of `Gadfly` as you on 32-bit Linux.

Comment: [v 0.3.1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31835846/versioninfo.JPG)

Comment: I have a very different platform, so I can't test your case.  Perhaps [filing an issue at Gadfly's GitHub repo](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues) will help.